# Why differentiate the generating function?

Tags: combinatorics

This question is regarding the [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1649339/number-of-inversions) written by @Marko Riedel. A generating function that counts the total number of inversions $k$ of all $n!$ is given as follows:

$$G(z) = \prod_{q=0}^{n-1} (1+z+z^2+\cdots +z^q).$$

In order to obtain the value of $k$ $G(z)$ is differentiated at $z=1.$ I do not understand why this is done. As far as I understand the coefficients of the generating function tell us how many permutations have a particular number of inversion. And so on evaluating $G(z)$ at $z=1$, we can get the total number of inversions since that would be the sum of all coefficients.

Comment: If you put $z=1$ you just get the total number of permutations $n!$. The coefficient of $z^k$ in $G(z)$ gives the number of those that have $k$ inversions.

Comment: i.e. Evaluation for $z=1$ will count all *permutations*, not all inversions. Since the coefficient of $z^k$ counts those permutations with $k$ inversions, differentiating yields $kz^{k-1}$ so that we multiply the number of permutations with $k$ inversions by $k$. Setting $z=1$ means we sum all these *inversions*.

Comment: Thank you very much for your comment! Please write this as an answer so that I can accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the polynomial

$$G(z) = \prod_{q=0}^{n-1} (1+z+z^2+\cdots +z^q)=\sum_{k=0}^{\binom{n}{2}}a_kz^k$$

the coefficient $a_k$ is the number of permutations with $k$ inversions, by substituting $z=1$ into the product we obtain $n!$, the total number of permutations.

However, if we differentiate with respect to $z$ we obtain

$$\frac{\text{d}G}{\text{d}z}=\sum_{k=1}^{\binom{n}{2}}a_kkz^{k-1}$$

so *now* setting $z=1$, since there are $a_k$ permutations with $k$ inversions, we obtain the *total* number of inversions in *all* $n!$ permutations

> $$\left(\frac{\text{d}G}{\text{d}z}\right)_{z=1}=\sum_{k=1}^{\binom{n}{2}}a_kk$$